# Creating tmp file in java using java nio classes , but to file name some random is getting appended , how to remove that?

Tags: java, nio

I am using java nio to create the tmp file like below

```
        Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("student_records", ".csv");
        Files.write(tempFile, fileContents);
        File file = tempFile.toFile();
        return new FileSystemResource(file);
```

but when file is created in temp directory , the file is not student_records.csv but student_records122334343443434.csv , i mean some random number is appending to the file , i do not want that random number , how to do that , and i want confirmation on if application exited, this tmp files deleted automatically or not ? can someone please help on this

Comment: why are you creating a Temp file then?

Comment: If you read the JavaDoc on `createTempFile` you'll see that what you pass to that method is a prefix and a suffix, so of course there will be some generated part as well. If you want an exact filename create a "normal" file in the temp directory (either use the "java.io.tmpdir" property to get the temp's root or create and use a subdirectory using `Files.createTempDirectory(name)`).

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour of `Files.createTempFile()`.

If you want a file that you can explicitly set the name of that does not exist after the application is closed, you can use:

```
File file = new File("student_records.csv");
file.deleteOnExit();
```

This will (as the name suggests) delete the file when the program exits.